# Why is output of {42.05 + 0.05 } like this on Dart Lang?

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-editor

When i try this on DartPad output is like this. Anyone can explain ?

[image]

Comment: That's a common error with floating numbers. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: In Java and Kotlin it's better to use BigDecimal instead of double. In dart you can try this https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/decimal (I didn't use this lib, so can't say how good it is)

Answer (score 3):

This is expected behavior. Double numbers cannot represent all decimal fractions precisely, and neither `0.05` nor `42.05` are the exact values that the `double` values represent.
The exact values are:

- 42.0499999999999971578290569595992565155029296875
- 0.05000000000000000277555756156289135105907917022705078125

If you add these two exact values, the result can yet again not be represented exactly as a double. The two closest representable doubles are:

- 42.099999999999994315658113919198513031005859375
- 42.10000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625

Of these, the former is closer to the correct result of the addition, so that is the `double` value chosen to represent that result.

This issue is not specific to Dart. All language using IEEE-754 64-bit floating point numbers will get the same result, and that is probably all languages with a 64-bit floating point type (C, C++, C#, Java, JavaScript, etc).